# Save child and parent at the same time

Tags: spring, kotlin, relationship

I need to save 2 models at the same time in the transaction, but...

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "book_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. My models:

a) Chapter

```
@Entity
class Chapter() : AuditModel() {

constructor(number: Int, title: String) : this() {
    this.number = number
    this.title = title
}

@Column(nullable = false)
var number: Int? = null

@Column(nullable = false)
lateinit var title: String

@Column(nullable = false)
var progress: Int = 0

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
lateinit var book: Book
}
```

b) Book

```
@Entity
class Book() : AuditModel() {

constructor(title: String, author: String) : this() {
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
}

@Column(nullable = false)
lateinit var title: String

@Column(nullable = false)
lateinit var author: String

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST])
val chapters: MutableSet<Chapter> = HashSet()
}
```

And function where I save models:

```
@Transactional
fun createBook(title: String, author: String): Boolean {
    val book = Book(title, author)
    val chapter = Chapter(1, "Example - 1")
    book.chapters.add(chapter)

    return bookRepository.save(book) != null
}
```

How to fix it? I'm new in Spring and it's totally incomprehensible to me.

Comment: It's extremely simple: the column chapter.book_id is mapped by the property Chapter.book. Chapter.book is null (i.e. never initialized anywhere). So the column is also set to null. And since your database table doesn't allow that, you get an exception.

Comment: lel? It's should work automatically? I added a new chapter to book.chapters, this chapter should know about book_id - or shouldn't?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It's your responsibility to keep both sides of the association in coherence, and the owner side is chapter.book, so JPA doesn't care about book.chapters

Comment: How to change it?

Comment: `chapter.book = book`

Comment: Any better options? It's doesn't look pretty good. It's stupid that it isn't set automatically by default.

Comment: Well, add an addChapter method to your Book class that does the right thing.